# Create XML at runtime

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I have a web service which expects input in xml format and input needs to be encoded. The environment i am working on is .NET 4.5 and code behind is c#. I have to include the encoded xml input in the SOAP request and send it to the service which sends back the output as SOAP response. I could send SOAP request and receive the response but i am having trouble in sending the xml input. The input involves data from oracle. For example i have a table customer

**Customer**

```
CustomerName | key       |  Value    |  
______________________________________
AAA          | Grocery   |  10       |
AAA          | Clothing  |  null     |
```

In the above table if the value has null i need to refer to the other table with foreign key = "key" and get the value from the other table.

I want to build the xml as i get value from query. So if i query the customer table by passing "AAA", first i have to read the grocery and the value 10 and the xml should look like

```
<customer>
 <Grocery>10</Grocery>
</customer>
```

Then i read the next row i see clothing then the value of clothing is null, so i would pass the orderType value (Clothing) to another table and get orderValue and append to the above xml to get the final xml

```
<customer>
  <Grocery>10</Grocery
  </Clothing>value from other table</Clothing>
</customer>
```

It is like building key value pair by getting values from database. For now i have code that reads all the values of a row using datareader.getValues and store it in array. I tried to create xml from the array but the problem is the xml is not getting added but is written overwritten.

```
using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(dbConnectionString))
        {
            conn.Open();
            using (OracleCommand comm = new OracleCommand(query, conn))
            {
                using (OracleDataReader dr = comm.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (dr.Read())
                    {
                        Object[] values = new Object[dr.FieldCount];
                        int fieldCount = dr.GetValues(values);


                        XElement xmlInput =
                                      new XElement("Document",
                                          new XElement(values[1].ToString(), values[0].ToString())
                                          );

                            XElement xmlTree = new XElement("Document");

                                foreach (XElement e1 in xmlInput.Elements())
                                {
                                    xmlTree.Add(new XElement("Document",
                                        new XElement(columnName,rowValue)));
                                }
                                xmlInput.Add(xmlTree);
                         }      
                    }
                }

            }
```

So how do i append the xml as i keep reading hey value pair in data reader?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that you have an array of key value pairs named for example 'allKeyValuePairs', you can easily create the XML structure that you posted by using this code:

```
XElement xmlDocument = new XElement("Customer");

foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> singlePair in allKeyValuePairs)
{
    xmlDocument.Add(new XElement(singlePair.Key, singlePair.Value));
}
```

The resulting XML will have structure like this:

```
<Customer>
  <Key1>Value1</Key1>
  <Key2>Value2</Key2>
  <Key3>Value3</Key3>
  ....
</Customer>
```

You were creating more elements with the same name 'Document', and then kept overwriting them by adding them to the same root element in a loop.

Comment: Thanks, that make sense. But is there a way to create xml as we read the values?

Comment: Yes, just call xmlDocument.Add to add new elements as you read new values. Only make sure that xmlDocument is referring to the same object you want to add values to.